# Timed AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and I have an aAax request as follows;

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
            data: "test_data"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == "true"){
                alert("true");
            }else{
                alert("false");
            }
        },
    });
```

This works well. But, I want to do this in a timely manner, in specific intervals of time. Say, I want to execute this every 30 seconds. The page should not be reloaded. I want this to happen in background, hidden. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
            data: "test_data"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == "true"){
                alert("true");
            }else{
                alert("false");
            }
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```

Comment: this is not exactly i am looking for. I want my script in a loop, to init every 30 seconds,no matter the result, just like alert "hi" for every 30 seconds.

Comment: Fixed! If you want to stop the timed requests, just store the setInterval return and destroy it later.

Answer (score 1):

Using setInterval? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Or if you only wanted it to run after a success message you could use setTimeout in the success callback to recall the function that sends that ajax request

Comment: +1. Just don't refer to w3schools, there are a lot of mistakes there.

Comment: I know, but I don't think that applies in this case and has a very basic, but useful write up :-)